# getting error assertion Failed in ipad

Tags: iphone

here is the error description-

Assertion failed: (cls), function getName, file /SourceCache/objc4_Sim/objc4-427.1.1/runtime/objc-runtime-new.m, line 3939.
modifying layer that is being finalized - 0x8142710

i am not getting what kind of error it is . please suggest